# Javascript if condition not working in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have this code:

```
if (Array.length === maxArrayLength) {
        alert("test1234");
        Array= [];
    }
```

which should display a message when the array `Array` has a length eequal to the variable `maxArrayLength`, but instead, it does nothing.

***But*** if I replace the `maxArrayLength` with `2` or a different number, it works.

There is a value in `maxArrayLength`, because when I do `console.log(maxArrayLength);` before (and after) the `if` statement, I get a value.

If it helps, this is in a Chrome Extension. The `maxArrayLength` is from `chrome.local.storage`:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('maxArray', function (items) {
    maxArray = items.maxArrayLength;
    console.log(maxArrayLength);
});
```

The `console.log` over here also works. I'm stumped. What's wrong? *It's as if the `if` statement can't access the `maxArrayLength` variable...?*

Comment: Array is a BAD variable name. Is that the actual name you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `typeof(maxArrayLength)` against the `typeof(Array.length)`.

By using `===` you're saying not only should the values be the same but also the data types.

For example:

```
"3" == 3 // true
"3" === 3 // false
```

Comment: Wow. I should've paid more attention when learning Javascript! I never knew that. I always thought it was strange that in most languages, you use `==` and JS used `===`. Thanks! Will remember in future :) +1

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly then, you just want compare value of variable maxArrayLength with Array.length so use == operator instead ===.

e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>

 <p>Click the button to create an array, then check it's length.</p>

 <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

 <p id="demo"></p>

 <script>
 function myFunction() {
    var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];        
    var maxArrayLength= 4;

   if (fruits.length == maxArrayLength){
     alert("Array length equals maxArrayLength");
   }

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yep. thanks! I never knew that as I said in @b1j's answer. he red first, so I accepted his. +1 though for teaching me something :)